# Configure ini file for HHVM 3.0 via socket with nginx

Tags: hiphop, hhvm

I'm able to start the HipHop VM to use a unix socket.  I can accomplish this via:

```
 /usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini  --mode daemon -vPidFile=/var/run/hhvm/pid -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.FileSocket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
```

However, I can't find a reference anywhere with how to set this in the `ini` file I'm specifying for my config.  To use a TCP port the line in server.ini is:

```
  hhvm.server.port = 9000
```

I've tried both

```
 hhvm.server.filesocket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
 hhvm.server.socket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
```

Both fail. Anyone know the file setting or where a reference for these settings can be found?

Comment: Although good question, It should be posted on Serverfault, it's about configuring server software, not about programing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although I can't find any documentation--they haven't yet written the updated version for the ini file format (as of 2014-05-01): https://github.com/hhvm/hack-hhvm-docs/issues/156

Regardless I figured it out and they confirmed it should be:

```
 hhvm.server.file_socket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
```

It looks like you take the camel case command line argument `-vServer.FileSocket` and drop the v, lowercase it, split it with underscores instead of camel case.

If y ou follow the above rewrite rules you can convert the old format to the new.

Comment: That is exactly correct. Can you please update whatever docs you were looking at to explain that?

Comment: @PaulTarjan  That's the problem... I can't find any docs on http://docs.hhvm.com/ about the options for new 'ini' config file format :/

Comment: @PaulTarjan I submitted a document bug for this at the github page... maybe and they're there I just overlooked them.